# DLL will not update

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, windows-server-2003

Im using a DLL for my asp.net website. I made changes to the DLL, and it works locally. But when I upload it to my server, it is still doing the old functionality.

The DLL is a .net 4.0 DLL, and the server is Server 2003 (with .Net 4.0 installed).

I tried gacutil /u DLL.dll but I get the error that it does not exist in the gac. Then I try doing a /i and it says successful, but still is not working well.

Ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend against using the GAC for web apps, unless this code is being used by a whole bunch of apps.  Just keep all your DLLs in the `/bin` directory.  Much simpler.

Comment: The DLL is being used by a windows app and a website, both running off the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the Temporary ASP.NET files. Remove the DLL form bin directory of the application. Paste the new version of dll in the application bin directory and access the page and see what happens.

The location of Temp ASP.NET files will be

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files

change the Framework folder name and version folder name as necessary